# Best Practice: Handling JS-free DELETE/PUT/PATCH

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

What is the current (and hopefully future-proof) best practice for JS-free DELETE/PUT/PATCH in SvelteKit ?

I couldn't find an example in the guide, and reviewing the lastest form proposal from Rich (https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5875), seems to depreciate `_method`.

Answer (score 0):

There probably just isn't any because HTML does not support that in the first place. As he stated:

> HTML forms can only be submitted with GET or POST.

And besides navigation, forms are the only way to generate requests without JS.

Comment: Yeah,  GET or POST are the only HTTP methods natively supported. Maybe I should have added it for context, but I thought it was obvious.

The question remains, how to handle/indicate other HTTP requests without JS - as  far as I know being able to do everything in sveltekit without JS is a principle of Rich.

Comment: You can handle whatever request you want via the `+server` file, but as stated, there is no way to send such requests *without* JS. Nobody can make that happen if the standards do not allow for it. If you want no-JS, use POST for everything that is modifying data.